# How to set the event for a disabled button in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

How to set the event for a disabled button in jquery.
I want to show a message when the mouse enter into the disabled button.
But now there is no event not occur while mouse enter the disabled button.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<div id="myid"><input type="submit"><div>

$('myid').click(function(event){
    if (attr('submit-button', 'disabled') == 'true')
    {
        alert('The button is disabled')
    }
});
```

Also check this [forum](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?186057-Disabled-button-stealing-onclick-events-in-firefox):

> Firefox, and perhaps other browsers, disable DOM events on form fields
>   that are disabled. Any event that starts at the disabled form field is
>   completely canceled and does not propagate up the DOM tree. Correct me
>   if I'm wrong, but if you click on the disabled button, the source of
>   the event is the disabled button and the click event is completely
>   wiped out. The browser literally doesn't know the button got clicked,
>   nor does it pass the click event on. It's as if you are clicking on a
>   black hole on the web page.